# Why is Jesus' lineage different in Matthew and Luke?

Tags: life-of-jesus, gospel-of-matthew, gospel-of-luke, genealogy

In [Matthew 1](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+1%3A1-17&version=NIV), there is a genealogy of Jesus from Abraham to Jesus, but in [Luke 3:23-28](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke+3%3A23-38&version=NIV), there is also a genealogy of Jesus from God to Adam to Jesus, but it's different to Matthews' version.

Why? And which one is correct?